# Processing time for Green Card after admission to US on immigrant visa

Tags: usa, visa, immigration, greencard

From your experience, **how long does it take** to get your plastic Green Card in the mailbox from the moment of entering the United States on immigrant visa?

The [USCIS](https://www.uscis.gov/file-online/uscis-immigrant-fee#Track%20Card%20Status) website specifies that if you don't get your card in 45 days after admission to the United States (considering the USCIS immigrant fee is already paid), you should request assistance. However, on some other website pages I found much longer processing times (from several weeks to several months).

Any indications regarding this matter will be greatly appreciated (please, specify the port of entry in your case, since different service centers may have different processing times).

Comment: Can you give some examples of web pages giving processing times of several months?  Are they relatively current?

Comment: This is not really a good site for polling random data. Try trakitt instead.

Answer (score 1):

Data point:  I know someone who got theirs about 5 months after entry.  The official timelines have quite a fantasy component.

Comment: Was that during the previous decade? My understanding is that there was a significant backlog for several years after September 2001, though I am only familiar with adjustment of status cases, not with immigrant visa cases.

Comment: @phoog No.  It was only a few years ago.  The backlog from application to entry is quite a different issue.

Comment: Adjustment of status cases are people who are already in the US on a nonimmigrant visa.